# force-download with Django and Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, force-download

**I was trying use vue to download file from server**

when I director visit my backends API, it work well，and I can unzip my file normal.

but when I try to download file by axios response, the file can not unzip，and also if I don't set link.download, the filename does not correct.like that
[image]

**here is my vue's api**

```
export function packMaterials (context, thesisId, filename) {
  context.$axios({
    method: 'get',
    headers: getAuthHeader(),
    url: PACK_URL + thesisId
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/force-download' })
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = filename
      link.click()
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

**here is my Django API**

```
 if os.path.exists(file_path):
    # 返回file
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={}".format(escape_uri_path(filename))
        return response
```

and here is the response data in console.
[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: and after I check , the md5 of file download by django api is same as the source file, and difference with the file download by vue, and the file download by vue is large then before.
what should I do?

Comment: I fixed it, I missed a configure in axios, it is needed to set responseType for axios like that.
responseType: 'blob'

Comment: I am getting compatibility issues with firefox.  Are you aware of any solutions?

Comment: I also appear compatibility issues with firefox, and I am not did well in frontend, so maybe I can't help you about it.